# Load onboard RTC device on NanoPi NEO from NAS kit

Tags: real-time-clock, nanopi, armbian

I have this [NanoPi NEO LTS](http://wiki.friendlyelec.com/wiki/index.php/NanoPi_NEO) device which I'm using in conjunction with [NAS Kit](http://wiki.friendlyelec.com/wiki/index.php/1-bay_NAS_Dock_v1.2_for_NanoPi_NEO/NEO2). [This](https://linux-sunxi.org/RTC) article states that Allwinner H3 (CPU) has an inbuilt RTC which is loaded to `/dev/rtc0` which I can confirm by running

```
ls -al /dev
Output:
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           4 ಏ  25 01:29 rtc -> rtc0
crw-------  1 root root    253,   0 ಏ  25 01:29 rtc0

cat /sys/dev/char/253\:0/name
Output:
sun6i-rtc 1f00000.rtc
```

But contrary to the last article, there is no `/dev/rtc1` which should be present since there is an onboard DS1307 RTC on the Kit itself. As a result, RTC resets on every reboot as the default one is the CPU's RTC.

I'm running Armbian Bullseye Minimal (Kernel 5.15.y). How do I load the onboard RTC?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [schematic](https://wiki.friendlyelec.com/wiki/index.php/File:SCHEMATIC_1-bay_NAS_Dock_v1.2.pdf), the DS1307 resides on I2C0.
You should check that your device tree contains a node for the DS1307.
It should more or less look like:

```
&i2c0 { 
        rtc@68 {
                compatible = "dallas,ds1307";
                reg = <0x68>;
        };
};
```

If your kernel is properly configured, you can check by:

- installing the Device Tree Compiler on your system: `sudo apt-get install device-tree-compiler`,
- Display the device tree in human readable for by executing: `dtc -I dtb -O dts /sys/firmware/fdt`.

You could first check your system can see the DS1307 by:

- Installing i2c-tools on your system: `sudo apt-get install i2c-tools`,
- Verify there is a device at address `0x68` on the I2C bus 0 by executing: `i2cdetect -y 0`.

Comment: First I had to enable i2c in the environment by adding `i2c` in the overlays section of `/etc/armbianEnv.txt`